# How to vertically center input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, transition

I'm currently struggling at maybe very simple thing but I can't figure it out how to make it. I've tried to read and use tricks and tips from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) or some older topics from here but none really helped me.

[This is my page and my goal is to center that heading and input vertically in middle of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td5qO.jpg)

Next thing I want to do with it is to animate that input and heading to the top of the screen. I'll be using react-spring transitions for it (since this is my React Weather App) and animation will be fired after successful **Axios** call. But that's another story. All I wanted to say with this explanation is that I think it will be nice to use some approach which is using **translateY** ,because in React-spring-transitions I'll be using something like this

```
  const forecastTransitions = useTransition(showForecast, null, {
    from: { opacity: 0,transform:'translateY(50px)' },
    enter: { opacity: 1,transform:'translateY(0px)' },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
  });
```

I've tried **display:flex** but it somehow broke my app. Input was a lot smaller and positioned a little to left. Second problem maybe can be that React-spring makes it's own **Animated div**.

```
  {inputTransitions.map(({ item, key, props }) =>
    item && <animated.div key={key} style={props}>

    <SearchForm 
      searchCity={searchCity} 
    />

    </animated.div>
  )}
```

So I don't know if I have to style that div, and try to vertically center it or what.

Does anybody know how to solve this kind of problem? Or if somebody know how to solve that thing with animation ,please respond here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `margin: 0 auto;` or if it doesn't work, apply the following style on the parent div:

```
.vertical-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: not working. I dont really know why.. I've tried everything

Comment: Please also check the height of the parent component. Most of the time, when working with components, the height of the component is wrapped to the content and is not 100%. This may be the reason the solution is not working.